# How to create an app on ElectronJS which after button click it logs out "Hello world!" in console?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, button, electron

Help me please!

Everything you can imagine and everything out of human imagination.
Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="hello-button">Hello World</button>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is renderer.js:

```
const helloButton = document.getElementById('hello-button');
helloButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Hello World');
});
```

Here is index.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question seems reasonably clear to me. The OP has the code posted above, this creates a basic electron app with a button labeled "Hello World". The OP expects the button to log "Hello World" to the console when clicked, but this is not happening. The last part is slightly ambiguous, as the code runs as expected, so possibly the OP is unaware as to how to access the dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is:

> How to create an app on ElectronJS which after button click it logs out "Hello world!" in console?

The code you posted above runs just fine and does log "Hello World" to the console when you click the button.

So the new question becomes why can you not see this output?

If you open the developer tools in the electron app like so:

[image: View menu option in Electron app]

Or using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then you will see the app's developer tools.

Select the *Console* tab, click the "Hello World" button and you will view the expected output.

[image: Output from developer console in Electron app]

Hopefully that helps, but if I've missed your meaning let me know and I'll revise my answer.